# How to create a single widget in the same GUI with tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a GUI that has two buttons: One checks whether the user has provided all the required inputs while the other runs a backend script. My problem is that this GUI will run for as long as the user wants to perform the backend task. The problem is: every time the user clicks on the 'check' button, another 'run' button is created right bellow the one last created. I need the 'run' button to be created at the same position every time the check button is clicked. I'm a newbie in python, btw. I'll appreciate if anyone can tell me if I got it all wrong. Thanks!

```
def verifica():

    fluxo=vfluxo.get()   
    permissoes=vpermissoes.get()
    results = vresults.get()


    if fluxo==2:
        label4 = Label(setup_window, text='Quantas tentativas (1-20)?')
        label4.pack()
        tentativas = Entry(setup_window)
        tentativas.pack()

    else:
        label5 = Label(setup_window, text='Ready!')
        label5.pack()

    def bot_setup():

        if fluxo==2:
            num_tentativas = tentativas.get()
            if num_tentativas == '' or int(num_tentativas) > 20:
            num_tentativas=0
            messagebox.showerror('ERRO!','Digite um tamanho de lote válido (1 a 20)')

        else:
            num_tentativas=1

        setup = {

            'tipo_operacao':fluxo,
            'permissoes':permissoes,
            'mostrarnofim':results,
            'tamanho_lote':int(num_tentativas)    
                }

        return setup

    comecar = Button(text='Run', command = bot_setup)
    comecar.pack()



verificar = Button(text='Check', command = verifica)
verificar.pack()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please fix the formatting of your code? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) if you don't know how to format your code on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's because you create a the Run-button every single time you click the `Check`-button. You can just create the `Run`-button outside of the `verifica()` function.

Comment: Is this your actual code you are running? With the same formatting? Because the `bot_setup()` function is defined inside the `verifica()` method (which is allowed, but seems strange/invalid in this case) and also the code to create the 'Run' button is part of the `verifica()` function. Without more information this seems a likely cause of your problem. If this is not the case, please provide a [mre] if you want a more useful answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Simon. I tried it but the run button wouldn't appear anymore. For now I'm going to use only one button to do everything. Thanks again!

Comment: That was also the problem, wovano. But because of a deadline, I decided to go with only one button. Thanks